# Render Viewport shows textures, final render does not (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, node-editor, shaders

first time posting and fairly new to Blender.

I've been working on a project for a couple of days, and so far everything has been working out pretty well. Today I was working on creating UV maps and had made some textures using Substance Painter. I got them working using the Shader editor (Node Editor) and everything looks good using rendered shading in the viewport, but when I go to `Render > Render Image` the output does not seem to have any of my texture data.

[image: Render in Viewport on left, render result on right.]
*Render in viewport on left, render result on right.*

Any suggestions would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved very quickly, I had another object that was on the same spot as my textured object (`Stick.save`) which was showing up in the render. I simply disabled it by clicking the `Enable/Disable in Renders` button on said object.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange. 
You should not to use Answer to share your own solution but can edit the question.

Comment: @RUben That is completely wrong. Answer should be **always** posted as answers to not bypass the community moderation progress (voting). Update or progress can be edits to the question. Please read this [section about answering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). It is encouraged to share your own solution by answering your own posts.